# mysql two tables with same entry name adding values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has basically a calendar entry for football games it looks like this

```
team1 || team1score || team2|| team2score || time || league
```

I want to update my positions table depending on entries from the calendar table.

so for example if I have in my table something like

```
Pats   || 14 || Saints || 3  || 1stleague
Cows   || 7  || falc   || 14 || 1stleague
Saints || 31 || falc   || 3  || 1stleague
Saints || 14 || cows   || 3  || 1stleague
```

I want a query that will first sum all the values in the team1score column with a distinct team1name.  So for the table above it would give as a result

```
Pats   || 14
Cows   || 7
Saints || 45
```

then I want to do the same thing for team2 and team2score so the result would be

```
Saints || 3
falc   || 17
cows   || 3
```

then I want to join these two results and get:

```
Pats   || 14
Cows   || 10
Saints || 48
falc   || 17
```

I tried something like this

```
select distinct(t.team1), sum(t.team1score)
  from calendar t
  where league = '5a7'
  UNION
    select distinct(t2.team2), sum(t2.team2score)
    from calendar t2
    where league = '5a7'
```

but its not adding the same teams scores any ideas?

I know I'm not taking the sums when I do the union but I think I need to do the union to keep the values that don't have a matching team on the teams2 column.  However I can't figure out how to do the union and sum at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use a sub-query to create a union of the team1 and team2 columns, aggregate the scores (only) in the outer query:

```
SELECT LOWER(t.team) team, SUM(t.score) score
FROM (
    SELECT team1 team, team1score score
    FROM calendar
    WHERE league='5a7'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT team2, team2score
    FROM calendar
    WHERE league='5a7'
) t
GROUP BY 1
```

**Edit:** In a `UNION`, the names/aliases of the select statements after the union are ignored. You can add `team` and `score`, if you think it improves the readability. However, it is not required.

**Edit:** Added `LOWER`, i.e. group case-insensitive.

Comment: should there be a score by team2score?

Comment: It is not adding the values from the different sides.  For example in my example it's not adding cows 7 + cows 3.